# Tent screen in Android

Tags: android

A friend has asked me if I can create an Android app that can change white to red/yellow or another colour in another app, so applying a tint to the screen for all apps until it's turned off.

I've no idea where to start on this, has anyone got knowledge of this? 
Can someone point me in the right direction of some reading?

Comment: glue some of [these](http://www.amazon.com/Color-Pack-Acetate-Transparent-Sheets/dp/B002MQJAYW/ref=pd_sim_hpc_2) onto the screen :D

Comment: actually, such an app would be quite cool since it could help those with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotopic_sensitivity_syndrome (their vision gets confused because different colors are not being processed synchronously)

Comment: Sorry for the bad question, wasn't really sure how to word it. This was actually an idea for my friend who is Dyslexic and has red tinted glasses for when she reads. So the Acetate as noah1989 mentioned is the effect I'm going for, but in an app.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so you can do this until and unless all other apps are not having background with 100% transparent.